# What is the default location of stack trace log in java on a stand alone machine?

Tags: stack-trace, java, logging

I am running a java program on my machine. I print the stack trace on console whenever an exception occurs. Where can i find the logs of those stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default prints to console, this won't be written to file. If you want it in file, you need to do Run Configurations--->Common--->Select 'File' and file location. Then you will see your stacktrace in that file.

Comment: That will be done only for that particular Exception trace. The program i am running is run through a script and runs for whole night.  What is the procedure to save all such trace to logs by default? Or do i need to handle it using my code?

Comment: AFAIK, it will log evrrything printed to console.